# Silverlight application for Windows Embedded

Tags: silverlight, windows-embedded

I am developing a Silverlight application for Windows Embedded and I am using Blend2 for making GUI.

SL for Windows Embedded will not support the C# code and we have to use C++ as we know this.

So my question is: I created a sample GUI in Blend2 and I created one button. When I click that button it should move to another screen  & it will show that and for this what should I put in function definition?

Comment: err, should belong on stackoverflow? (never thought i'll say that...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is about making your first steps in this technology, I would recommend to take a look on this [tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx). I also found this [video tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2010/06/23/combining-net-compact-framework-and-silverlight-for-windows-embedded.aspx) regarding using .net compact framework with Silverlight for Windows Embedded, you may find it useful too.